# Interaction between Java 2D graphics and ccSvcHst.exe

Tags: java, graphics2d

My first posted question here, so I'm begging forgiveness in advance for my question-formatting inexperience.

My 2D graphics game normally runs perfectly on my system.  But when Norton Internet Security’s ccSvcHst.exe process is running with very high CPU utilization, it has strange interactions with the game.  I have identified the specific lines of Java code which are impacted.

```
// Graphics setup, just trying to give some background
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = e.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration grafConf = device.getDefaultConfiguration(); 
Frame f = new JFrame(grafConf);
device.setFullScreenWindow(f);
f.createBufferStrategy(2);
BufferStrategy buffStrat = f.getBufferStrategy();
Graphics grafx = buffStrat.getDrawGraphics();

// Create some sprites to draw here...

// Launch a game loop to execute every 15ms
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() { public void run() { gameLoop(); }};
timer.schedule(task,0,15);

public void gameLoop() {
    BufferedImage erase = getEraseBI();
    // Erase each the 64x64 sprites...
    int x, y; x = getX(1); y = getY(1);
    long t1start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    grafx.drawImage(erase, x, y, null);
    long t1end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    x = getX(2); y = getY(2);
    long t2start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    grafx.drawImage(erase, x, y, null);
    long t2end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // and so on, for each sprite to erase

    // Move stuff and redraw it; no problems here...

    // Now flip the page to show what we’ve drawn
    long show1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    buffStrat.show();
    long show2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    grafx.dispose();
    grafx = buffStrat.getDrawGraphics();
}
```

Normally, the drawImage() and buffStrat.show() calls execute so fast that the difference between the two times shows as 0.  But after a couple of minutes, when there are more than about a dozen sprites to erase, one or more of the drawImage() calls (but not all of them), as well as the buffStrat.show() call suddenly take 25-35ms instead of 0.  This behavior persists until the game is stopped.  Rebooting the system clears the high-CPU ccSvcHst condition, restoring normal, stable, play-for-3-hours-straight-without-any-issues game performance.

Without getting into a political discussion about the merits of Norton tools, I'm just curious - has anyone else seen this interaction between Java graphics and NIS ccSvcHst.exe?